# Double Page Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a single page website with a 'click to scroll' navigation which works fantastic. Code for such a link is shown below;

```
<li><a href="#" data-scroll="contact">Contact<hr></a></li>
```

Using media queries, when in mobile version, my website removes the navigation and replaces it with a hidden drop-down menu, link is shown below;

```
<a href="#" data-scroll="contact"><div class="col-xs-3 media-nav-contact"><p>Contact</p></div></a>
```

This link however refuses to adopt the 'click to scroll' navigation? Any ideas as to why?

Here is a Fiddle to have a look http://jsfiddle.net/nK988/1/

Comment: FYI You cannot put a div inside an <a tag>. Invalid mark-up. Could you add more code (HTML,CSS, JS) in a js fiddle? It is difficult to debug like that, thanks. I assume you are using Jquery Mobile or other to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks! I never knew that :) learn something new every day huh! still no luck though, I'll get a jsfiddle up ASAP and add it to my original question. Thanks @Sigma

Comment: I have just added a jsfiddle to my original question @Sigma for some reason the initial 'click to scroll' isn't working in the jsfiddle but I may be making a school boy error on that one as I am new at using these fiddles. Perhaps because I'm using an external script? You may well be able to spot the problem right away :) Thanks got all your help!

Comment: You were using onload better ondomready.  http://jsfiddle.net/HA2qu/2/ Also I would scroll the clicked section up just under the header.

Comment: Thats not a terrible recommendation, I think I might change the order up a little. What about the mobile navigation links, the hidden ones, any idea as to why there not finding and scrolling down to the section in question @Sigma ??

Comment: It does scroll but you cannot see it scroll when the window is maximized. You see the scrolling when the section is out of view = below the viewport (make your window height small).

Comment: ahh I see, so if the mobile navigation slided BELOW the header then we would be able to see some scrolling right? @Sigma

Comment: I would have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/